# Normal distribution (why $\Phi(0,1)=0.5\Phi(-1,1)$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading "Probability" by Pitman and in the section that talks about normal distribution states:  $\Phi(0,1)=0.5\Phi(-1,1)$.

Can someone explain this equality ?

Comment: Yes. **Symmetry**.

Comment: If $\Phi(a,b)$ is the probability that a standard normal random variable lies between $a$ and $b$, then this follows from the fact that the normal distribution is symmetric about its mean, in this case zero. So $\Phi(-1,0) = \Phi(0,1)$ and $\Phi(-1,1) = \Phi(-1,0) - \Phi(0,1) = 2\Phi(0,1)$.

Comment: @RahulNarain - if $\Phi(-1,0)=\Phi(0,1)$ then $\Phi(-1,0)-\Phi(0,1)=0$...Why $\Phi(-1,1)=\Phi(-1,0)-\Phi(0,1)=2\Phi(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Oops, I meant $\Phi(-1,1) = \Phi(-1,0) + \Phi(0,1) = 2\Phi(0,1)$, with a plus sign. You know that $\Phi(a,b) + \Phi(b,c) = \Phi(a,c)$, right?

Comment: @RahulNarain - I think so...it depends if I understand right - is $\Phi(a,b)=\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)$ a definition or a theorem ? if it's the definition then it's ok..

Comment: I don't know, check your book. But how does it matter?

Comment: If it's the definition then I understand it, if it's a theorem then I don't understand the theorom hence I don't rally understand this statement..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi(b)$ be the cumulative distribution function of the normalized normal distribution. That is, $\Phi(b)=P(X<b)$. Then it's convenient to introduce $\Phi(a,b)=\Phi(b)-\Phi(b)$, which expresses the probability $P(a<X<b)$. (Could also be written as $P(a\le X<b)$, which is the same probability because $P(X=a)=0$.) Since $X$ is symmetric, 
$$P(0<X<1)=P(-1<X<0) \\ = \frac12 (P(0<X<1)+P(-1<X<0)) \\ =\frac12 P(-1<X<1)$$